# Problem with wi-fi after updating Nexus S to Android 4

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Nexus S phone doesn't detect any wi-fi networks after the update to Ice Cream Sandwich.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've just manually updated my GSM T-Mobile Nexus S and it connected automatically to my home wi-fi, I had all the previous settings stored, and I'm also detecting all the wi-fis from my neighbours.

Could you give more details about your issue?

Comment: My nexus S also connected automatically to my wi-fi network, download update and install the package but when it restart my wifi didn't work.